# Simple sub-field bind with AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to bind a sub-field of a component to a input string. Here is a simplified version of the code.

**my_component.dart**

```dart
class A {
    String text;
}

@ng.Component(
    selector: 'my-component'
)
class MyComponent {
    A a;
}
```

**my_component.html**

```dart
<div>
    {{a.text}}
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="a.text">
</div>
```

An this is the error I get once I type anything on the input box.

**Error**

```dart
type '_LinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'A' of 'value'.
```

It is possible to bind a subfield in AngularDart? If so, what is the proper way of doing it?

**Edit**

It now works if I add a constructor like this

```dart
MyComponent(this.a);
```

But I am still fighting this more general case

```dart
@ng.Injectable()
class B {
    String text;
}

@ng.Injectable()
class A {
    B b;

    A (this.b);
}

@ng.Component(
    selector : "my-component",
    template: '{{a.b.text}} Name: <input type="text" ng-model="a.b.text">'
)
class MyComponent {
    A a;

    MyComponent(this.a);
}
```

The error now is

```dart
Missing getter: (o) => o.b
...
Exception: The null object does not have a method 'call'.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of 'A']
```

**Edit 2**

My module configuration is

```dart
class MyAppModule extends Module {
    MyAppModule() {
        bind (MyComponent);
        bind (A);
        bind (B);
    }
}

//Inside main()
applicationFactory()
    .addModule(new MyAppModule())
    .run();
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```dart
transformers:
- redstone_mapper
- angular:
    html_files:
    - lib/client/models/evento/evento.html ##Actually not using this in the example
```

**Edit 3**

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angulardart.org/issues/70) on AngularDart for anyone interested.

**Edit 4**

Adding/changing it to this makes it work

```dart
@ng.Component
(
    selector : "my-component",
    template: '{{text}} Name: <input type="text" ng-model="text">'
)
class EventoComponent
{
    ...
    String get text => a.b.text;
    set text (String v) => a.b.text = v;
    .
}
```

but practically kills the point of having structure since you have to flatten it yourself.

Comment: I can't see something wrong. Your're sure you have the latest versions of packages and transformer set up properly.

Comment: Maybe just the error message is misleading. If you don't initialize `a` (assign a value to it) this can't possibly work. Instead of the constructor `A a = new A()` would work as well. Only you can not what you try to accomplish and how you want the field be initialized, but you just can't reference `a.b` when `a` is null.

Comment: The error now is `Missing getter: (o) => o.b`. But why would it try to get `a.b` before constructing `a`? The same should have happened when you tried to reach `a.text` in the previous version.

Comment: Do you have a modul configuration that configures what to inject when you have constructor which requires an instance of `A` or `B`?

Comment: Do you get a different error message when you simplify the template to `template: '{{a.b.text}}'`

Comment: I update some info on the actual error. I don't have any configuration on the dependencies (no idea how to do that). I'll check the simplification.

Comment: Same error on the simplification.

Comment: If you want the injector to pass instances to your constructors youe need a Module configuration like show at https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_06/web/main.dart#L16 otherwise nothing gets assigned which naturally leads to the error message you get.

Comment: See Edit 2 for my Module configuration. I had it. The error prevails.

Comment: Do you also pass an instance of the module to the `applicationFactory`? ` applicationFactory()
      .addModule(new MyAppModule())
      .run();` like shown a few lines below.

Comment: Looks fine so far. You have configured the transformer? https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_06/pubspec.yaml#L11

Comment: Yeah, the transformer is there.

Comment: `my_component.html` is missing

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah, its not actually called my_component. Its really called `evento.html`, but as you can see I am not using a template URL and instead embedding the short template directly since the second edit.

Comment: I see. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Opened an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angulardart.org/issues/70

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what is your approach on hierarchical structures?

Comment: I didn't work with Angular in the last 6 months.